# SUM / IF with INNER JOIN in MySQL--how to turn it into a knex query?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, knex.js

I have this MySQL statement below that works as intended. Feel great about that...but...

I am struggling with how to get this into a knex.js query builder. There is no ".selectRaw" in the knex.js docs that I have seen. I've only been able to sum one column with knex.js. The knex.js doesn't seem to address this. The idea is that there are upvotes & downvotes on what I am building. I want to know the votes for each category, and then a sum total (up + down = total).  I am trying to avoid breaking this up into different queries. I haven't found any good samples yet.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

```
    use iconwebsite;
    SELECT 
        i.icon_description,
        SUM(IF(v.vote_score > 0, v.vote_score, 0)) AS up,
        SUM(IF(v.vote_score < 0, v.vote_score, 0)) AS down,
        SUM(IF(v.vote_score, v.vote_score, 0)) AS total
        
    FROM
        icon i
            INNER JOIN
        vote v ON i.icon_id = v.icon_id
    GROUP BY i.icon_description;
```

Comment: I don't understand the point of the third IF (and in MySQL, the first two are redundant)

Comment: Presumably you already have a connection to your database elsewhere within your code, so I'd imagine that 'use iconwebsite' is redundant too, but if you need to specify db in query, just prefix tables with 'iconwebsite.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use raw SQL with knex like that with your query:

```js
knex.select(knex.raw(`
    use iconwebsite;
    SELECT 
        i.icon_description,
        SUM(IF(v.vote_score > 0, v.vote_score, 0)) AS up,
        SUM(IF(v.vote_score < 0, v.vote_score, 0)) AS down,
        SUM(IF(v.vote_score, v.vote_score, 0)) AS total
        
    FROM
        icon i
            INNER JOIN
        vote v ON i.icon_id = v.icon_id
    GROUP BY i.icon_description;
`))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I am looking at what you send me on knex.js...still not grasping it. What would it look like with the sum if given the context I have provided?

Comment: If you can, stick to the raw SQL, it's so liberating :)

Comment: I'm also puzzled as to how this helps

Comment: I updated the answer to show how it is used in topicstarter's case. @paul-w, is it what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes, I got it. I found this after posting the question and cobbled together something that worked. https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/1606

Comment: You shouldn't need outer `knex.select(...)` there. Now the created query will be like `select use iconwebsite; select i.icon_...`